# MySQL delete records between 'n' rows

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select records between let's say 2nd and 5th row. My id's are not in sequentially order so I tried to retrieve the `row_number` this way:

```
SELECT  @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
FROM    product_image p
JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
WHERE   row_number BETWEEN 2 AND 5
```

My table is kind of:

```
id  name 
23  A
42  B
98  C
102 D
109 E
```

What I get is `row_number column doesn't exist` and it really does not exist. But how can retrieve the records between 2 and 5 ( 3th and 4th )? I red similar post but didn't understand the query well. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The order of rows in a mysql DB is not guaranteed. So it is very riski to do what you ae trying

Comment: Well, yes I red that also :) But  I am most interested in how to build this kind of query :)

Comment: you can utilise TOP to solve this. its like select top 2 records from the table where the id is not in top 2

Comment: @RishikeshDhokare MySQL doesn't support TOP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't really need to select the row number, there is no need to rely on *undocumented "features"* like `@curRow := @curRow + 1`. Just use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`. To select the rows from `2` to `5` you would just need

```
select id
from product_image
order by name, id
limit 4
offset 1
```

Note that you need a well defined `ORDER BY` clause. Otherwise the result can depend on what index has been used by the engine.

To delete those rows, use a `DELETE .. JOIN` statement

```
delete product_image
from product_image
join (
  select id
  from product_image
  order by name, id
  limit 4
  offset 1
)x using(id)
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66fa4/1

No tricks. No complex queries.

Answer (score 3):

The reason the query fails is that you can't use column aliases in a `WHERE` clause. You can however use them in a `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT  *, @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
FROM    product_image p
JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
GROUP BY row_number
HAVING row_number between 2 and 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `DELETE` with `JOIN`:

```
DELETE p
FROM product_image p
INNER JOIN (    
   SELECT  id,  @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
   FROM    product_image p
   CROSS JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
   ORDER BY id
) AS t ON p.id = t.id
WHERE t.row_number IN (2,3)
```

Derived tabe `t` is created using your query. You can join to this table in order to identify any records you want and delete them.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f7f749/1)

Answer (score 1):

Check this -
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c462d/5

```
select * from 
    (
    SELECT  @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number,p.*
    FROM    product_image p
    JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r)
    a 
    WHERE   a. row_number BETWEEN 2 AND 5
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a synthetic row number to a query, you need a subquery. Like so.

```
SELECT id FROM (
          SELECT    p.*, @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
            FROM    product_image p
            JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
         ) q
 WHERE   row_number BETWEEN 2 AND 5
```

Then, you can, if you wish, use the result to drive a delete operation.

```
   DELETE FROM product_image
    WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id FROM (
              SELECT    p.*, @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
                FROM    product_image p
                JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
             ) q
     WHERE   row_number BETWEEN 2 AND 5
    )
```

But this is an **extremely bad thing to do.** Why? You're relying on a particular order in the result set of your inner query. The rows in a SQL result set are, without any `ORDER BY` clause, returned in an unpredictable order.  Server optimizers exploit this. Unpredictable is like random, but worse. Random implies that it's unlikely the order will be the same each time you run the query. Random here is good because you'll catch your problem during testing. Unpredictable, on the other hand, means the order remains the same *until it doesn't.* If you're not sure why that's bad, look up Murphy's law.

Comment: What if retrieve only 6 records and order them by `sort` (let's say) column. Something like `SELECT ... WHERE prod_id=36 ... ORDER BY sort ASC` and than get the 3th and the 4th one. Will this be acceptable?

Comment: Yes, if you use a determined sort order you do not have the "unpredictabity" problem.